# How to get the values entered in the field Filtered DataTable of Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I have a data table:

```
<p:dataTable id="pDataTableListaRegistros"
             var="registro"
             value="#{arquivoBean.listaRegistros}"
             paginator="true"
             rows="20"
             filteredValue="#{arquivoBean.filteredListaRegistros}"
             styleClass="tabelaCentralizada">
```

I would like to get the values ​​entered in filter fields "Code", "Data do Registro" and "Usuário" to manipulate in a backing bean.

[image]

Comment: I know to get the value entered in a <p:inputText>. This is possible through the get and set methods of backingBean. However I do not know to get the value entered in a field Filtered column:

<p:column headerText="Código" sortBy="#{registro.codigoRegistro}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{registro.codigoRegistro}" styleClass="fontColunaTabela8pt">

Comment: You should not do that in a getter/setter method. They should be kept untouched and not do anything else than just returning and setting a property. You should just access the `listaRegistros` in the action method. JSF has already set the values in there.

Comment: i don´t know how to get the values typed by the user in the column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the filter value from the datatable by

1. Obtain a reference to the datatable from the view either by binding or walking the tree. By binding, you'll have:

   ```
      <p:dataTable binding="#{arquivoBean.theDataTable}" id="pDataTableListaRegistros" var="registro" value="#{arquivoBean.listaRegistros}" paginator="true" rows="20" filteredValue="#{arquivoBean.filteredListaRegistros}" styleClass="tabelaCentralizada"/>
   ```

   And in your backing bean:

   ```
      DataTable theDataTable = new DataTable();
      //getter and setter
   ```
2. From the binding

   ```
      Map<String, String> theFilterValues = theDataTable.getFilters(); //This returns a map of column-filterText mapping.
   ```

Comment: How to get it from Javascript ?

Comment: @rashidnk Why would you need them in JavaScript? Can't you just simply query the DOM?

Comment: Note: only bind to request scoped beans, never bind to view or session scope as it might cause duplicate IDs

Answer (score 1):

You can add a map to your bean, like:

```
private Map<String, Serializable> filterValues = new HashMap<>();
```

And bind the values to the map using the `filterValue` attribute of `p:column`, for example:

```
<p:column headerText="Name"
          sortBy="#{item.name}"
          filterBy="#{item.name}"
          filterMatchMode="contains"
          filterValue="#{yourBean.filterValues['name']}">
  <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
</p:column>
```

Advantage of this solution is that the values will be kept when you update your table.